# Hide services passwords in Cake Build

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I am using Cake build to build and deploy a project but in my script I have a few services passwords which I do not want to expose.

Is it possible to read the passwords from an external file (maybe JSON?) which I would not push to Github? So this file would be only in my computer.

Is there a standard way to do this with Cake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store that password as an environment variable on the system you are running the build on.  From there, you can then use the `EnvironmentVariable` alias to request that value, to then use it within your script:

http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/EnvironmentAliases/F508FA2B

This is how we store/use the secrets associated with the build process for Cake itself.  See here for an example:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/build/credentials.cake#L15

Taken from this link is the following code snippet:

```
public static BuildCredentials GetGitHubCredentials(ICakeContext context)
{
    return new BuildCredentials(
        context.EnvironmentVariable("CAKE_GITHUB_USERNAME"),
        context.EnvironmentVariable("CAKE_GITHUB_PASSWORD"));
}
```

Where we are reading two environment variables, the username and the password, which are then used later in the script execution.

**NOTE:** The presence of the `context` variable is due to the fact that we are doing the work in the helper function, where the main Cake Context was passed in as a parameter.  This will not be required if you are accessing the `Environment` alias directly in one of your tasks.

Assuming you are using some form of Continuous Integration, then there will likely be a way either through a configuration file, or through a User Interface, to specify the values of these environment variables in a secure manner.